# <HTA:Application will refuse to work on ie10+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, microsoft-edge, hta

On my desktop HTA app I have some HTA:Application styling. But when I set this tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE">` The HTA Application styling is completely voided. If the meta is set to `content="IE=9"` The hta will be processed and functional. My question is how can I get my HTA to work.

Comment: Use the `content="IE=9"`? I'm confused... Of course it won't work if you set it to EDGE... Still confused. What exactly is it you want to achieve?

Comment: ^^ + HTA is deprecated since IE10, and when run in IE>9 mode, all the actual HTA features are out of use, though the security model work with newer IEs too. Hence true HTAs are stucked to stay in level of IE9, untill MS removes IE from the OS in the future.